# !gcloud config get-value compute/region returns unset while the regions is been set ( vertexaiworkbench notebook )

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workbench, google-cloud-vertex-ai

im using vertexai wokbench to run my code ,
i can define my project using the command :

```
!gcloud config get-value project
```

but when i ran the command to get my default region :

```
!gcloud config get-value compute/region
```

i get unset .
however i already set the config of compute/region of my project in my vs code when i a already authenticated :
[image]

are the changes made in vs code not applied ? or the workbench isn't getting the configs ? if so why does he recognise the project ?
i already tried to retard the kernel and it doesnt work.

thank you

Comment: I'm not much of a Windows person, but it looks like you're running inside a conda/anaconda environment, so if I had to guess, when you set it with VS code, that wasn't within the same environment?  Can you query your settings from a non-conda/anaconda env shell?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, you have setup some metadata using gcloud command on your local machine and you want to check the same metadata when using a Vertex AI Workbench instance.

Is that correct?

If yes, this kind of configuration (ie. compute/region configuration), must be done on the Vertex Workbench instance on the same way as you did on your local machine - like using `gcloud config set compute/region [region name]`. The same way as in your local machine, it must be run only once at your Vertex Workbench instance for the same user.

The reason it does recognize the project is because project configuration is something created when you setup gcloud cli -- but default compute/region and/or compute/zone are not default values.

Comment: I think he said he already set it in VS code (and as per screenshot)

Comment: what I said has nothing to do with VSCode, Glen

Comment: You're right -- my bad.  It was me who misread your post :D

Comment: Thank you , and sorry for the delay to answer. i'll try this asap and get back to you to see if it works